# MassTransit and Unity IOC container integration

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, unity-container, masstransit

I'm having an issue with MassTransit and my IoC container (Unity), regarding to named registrations. Just to clarify my problem, I have the following piece of code:

```
public class CommandHandlerToConsumerAdapter<T> : Consumes<T>.All
        where T : class, ICommand
    {
        private readonly ICommandHandler<T> m_commandHandler; //object responsible for performing the expected actions with the received message

        public CommandHandlerToConsumerAdapter(ICommandHandler<T> _commandHandler)
        {
            m_commandHandler = _commandHandler; //injected property
        }

        public void Consume(T _message) //receives the message
        {
            m_commandHandler.Handle(_message); //does the logic
        }
    }
}
```

The `CommandHandlerToConsumerAdapter<T>` is an adapter class, used to provide a lesser degree of coupling between the projects that reference MassTransit. Since all the messages I'm publishing/subscribing to implement the interface `ICommand`, it makes sense having this class, which receives an message through the implementation of the `Consumes<SomeCommand>.All` interface and maps it to its corresponding `Handle()` method, which belongs to class that implements the interface `ICommandHandler<T>` and is injected into the `CommandHandlerToConsumerAdapter` constructor.

The problem comes now, when I have to register all those interfaces to their corresponding implementations. Basically I want the same message to be subscribed by two different classes that will handle it, through my adapter class. So I register the interface to the respective classes that implement it, using named registrations:

```
container.RegisterType<ICommandHandler<Command>, CommandLogic>("CommandLogic");
container.RegisterType<ICommandHandler<Command>, CommandHandler>("CommandHandler");
```

And then I want both of the classes to receive messages through my adapter class. For so, I register them as follows, injecting one different `ICommandHandler` implementation to each:

```
container.RegisterType<Consumes<Command>.All, CommandHandlerToConsumerAdapter<Command>>("CommandLogic", new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter(typeof(ICommandHandler<Command>), "CommandLogic")));
container.RegisterType<Consumes<Command>.All, CommandHandlerToConsumerAdapter<Command>> ("CommandHandler", new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter(typeof(ICommandHandler<Command>), "CommandHandler")));
```

However, by doing that, I don't achieve the expected result, which is that both classes `CommandHandlerToConsumerAdapter<Command>`, with an injected property `CommandLogic`, and`CommandHandlerToConsumerAdapter<Command>`, with an injected property `CommandHandler`, receive messages of type `Command` and treat them accordingly by objects `CommandLogic` and `CommandHandler` respectively, through my `CommandHandlerToConsumerAdapter` adapter class.

For now only the last registered class is receiving messages and treating them. Does anyone have a clue on how could I subscribe to the same message type through this approach? Maybe I'm screwing something up in the registration to the IoC container...

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the code you have posted.  I have tried it and can resolve both instances with `container.ResolveAll<Consumes<Command>.All>();`.  Can you post your code that resolves the collection of command handlers and calls to them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple consumers for the same message through Unity not working in MassTransit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20710607/multiple-consumers-for-the-same-message-through-unity-not-working-in-masstransit)