# MassTransit & Unity - How can I avoid duplicate messages from being sent to consumers?

Tags: rabbitmq, unity-container, message-queue, servicebus, masstransit

We are using MassTransit/RabbitMQ and Unity. I've noticed that each consumer is receiving a single message twice. I have looked at [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20710607/multiple-consumers-for-the-same-message-through-unity-not-working-in-masstransit) where other's are describing this issue as well. I'm clear as to what, specifically is the cause. However all fingers seem to be pointed to MT's SubScriptionBusConfigurator.LoadFrom(IUnityContainer container) method.

I am registering several consumers with my Unity container like so:

```
 container.RegisterType<ConsumerA>();
 container.RegisterType<ConsumerB>();
 container.RegisterType<ConsumerC>();
```

My consumers are all listening for the same message:

```
public class ConsumerA : Consumes<SomeMessage>.All
{
  public void Consume(SomeMessage message)
  {
     ...
  }
}
```

My service bus registration looks like:

```
container.RegisterType<IServiceBus>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(), new InjectionFactory(x => ServiceBusFactory.New(sbc =>
            {
                sbc.ReceiveFrom("rabbitmq://localhost/service_bus");
                sbc.UseRabbitMq();
                sbc.UseNLog();
                sbc.Subscribe(s => s.LoadFrom(container));
                sbc.Subscribe(s => s.Handler<IFault>((context, message) =>
                  _logger.Error(string.Format("ServiceBus Fault: {0}", message.FaultType))));
            })));
```

After some looking around it seems that my subscription is the problem:

```
sbc.Subscribe(s => s.LoadFrom(container));
```

So what is the correct/preferred way to register my consumers so that messages are not sent to each consumer twice??

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The container specific `LoadFrom` makes a lot of assumptions. Some of them might be incorrect for you.

I'd suggest changing the calls to `sbc.Subscribe(s => container.Resolve<ConsumerA>())`, etc. `LoadFrom` is a convenience method and if it's no longer convenient for whatever reason, just skip it.

Comment: Same thing is happening with AutoFact and the AsSelf().AsImplementedInterfaces() the system is getting twice the messages.